# php preg_replace_all do I need to define $matches?

Tags: php, netbeans, pass-by-reference

I typically call preg_match_all using `$pattern`, `$subject`, `$matches`, like

```
preg_match_all("/\S/","words",$matches);
```

However, my `IDE (Netbeans)` is yelling at me because `$matches` (which is passed by reference and will be assigned the result of `preg_match_all`) is undefined so it doesn't want me to pass it as a parameter. Its happy with something like:

```
$matches=[];
preg_match_all("/\S/","words",$matches);
```

However, this seems superfluous, and the examples on php.net do not define the variable ahead of time. What is the "proper" way to do this? Can I just ignore `Netbeans`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore NetBeans. As you say, the PHP manual doesn't define the variable, and I've tested it with all error reporting on and no notice error is given.

Also, the IDE I use, PHPStorm, doesn't show an undefined error for the `$matches` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You may safely ignore Netbeans, or you may [configure Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226198) to complain less.

It may be considered good style to declare your variables before use, even when those variables are output-only.  PHP doesn't care: PHP will overwrite whatever `$matches` is before hand even if it doesn't exist:

```
$matches = new StdClass();
$ok = preg_match_all('/foo/', "foo bar", $matches);
var_dump($ok, $matches);
```

Whether that's a good, or a bad, thing is user-defined. :)

Finally, you may consider a helper function which will both quiesce Netbeans and reduce your typing:

```
function get_matches($pattern, $subject, $options = null) {
    $matches = array ();
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, $options);
    return $matches;
}
```